# Woocommerce/Wordpress: how to trigger one filter's code from another filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am configuring a Woocommerce store, and I want to allow users from some locations to browse my site, but not allow them to buy: if they try, there should be a message asking them to email us for a custom shipping quote, and the payment methods should be removed.

I have configured two shipping zones: the locations that we do serve and every other one, and I have left the latter without any shipping methods. This way, if an user enters a shipping address we cannot serve, there won’t be any shipping methods available.

Now, I can use these filters to run code when there are no shipping methods available:

```
woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html
woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html
```

And I can filter out the available payment gateways, even removing all of them, using the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` filter...

...but how do I call one of them from the other?

From what I've seen, the [WC_Payment_Gateways class](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Payment-Gateways.html) doesn't seem to have any method to manipulate by hand the available payment methods: all you can do is to load them (`get_available_payment_gateways()`), but
I get the distinct impression that you are not supposed to touch that object "by hand", and you are supposed to do that in the appropriate filter (`woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`). So, again, how do I trigger that filter's code from the previous filter?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found an answer in the Wordpress Stackexchange and followed it:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213219/using-variable-from-one-filter-in-another-filter

Basically, I created a singleton object to keep global state. The code in `woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html` writes to it saying "there are no shipping methods", and then the code in `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` checks it and, if that's the case, it removes all payment gateways.

It's something like this:

```
if( ! class_exists('Vuelamedia_EstadoGlobal')) {
    class Vuelamedia_EstadoGlobal {
        private $hayMetodoDeEnvio;
        private static $instance;
        
        private function __construct() {
            $this->hayMetodoDeEnvio=true;
            }
    
        public static function getInstance() {
            if(is_null(self::$instance)) {
                self::$instance = new self();
               }
            return self::$instance;
            }

        public function guardaValor($valor=TRUE) {
            $this->hayMetodoDeEnvio = $valor;
            }
            
        public function leeSiHayMetodoDeEnvio() {
            return $this->hayMetodoDeEnvio;
            }
        }
    }


add_filter("woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html", "quitar_formas_de_pago", 20);
add_filter("woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html", "quitar_formas_de_pago", 20);

function quitar_formas_de_pago($texto) {

    Vuelamedia_EstadoGlobal::getInstance()->guardaValor(false);
    return $texto;
    }


add_filter("woocommerce_available_payment_gateways", "filtrar_formas_de_pago");
function filtrar_formas_de_pago($available_gateways) {
   if( is_admin() ) { return $available_gateways; }
   
   $metodo = Vuelamedia_EstadoGlobal::getInstance()->leeSiHayMetodoDeEnvio();

    if (!$metodo) {
        return array();
        }
    else { return $available_gateways; }
    }
```